# Datagrid wont sort

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, datagrid

I have a project, where all DataGrids sort just fine except for one. Going through the construction of the Flex components, I don't detect any differences, but when I click the column header, nothing happens, I mean, I see the button feedback, but the fields just wont sort. If click other columns in the same DataGrid, it does sort, it's just one column not working.

I'm using an old version of Flex SDK: 3.0.1, so, no Spark.

Any tests I could do to see what could be happening?.

Thanks.

Edit.: It works only DESC order, I mean, when I order the datagrid by some other columns, I can click the problematic column and it does order once, and DESC only, if I click it again, it doesn't order ASC back.

Comment: Are you using Itemrenderer? if not whta is the data type of the column content?

Comment: Sounds like you may be sorting a string date. You may want to use the debug version of the Flash Player if you are not already (to see more detailed information). You may also want to consider using a custom sortCompareFunction. If you are already using a sortCompareFunction then you may want to check that the name for the  field being compared is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was missing the dataField property, once I assigned it, it started to work again. Thanks everyone anyway.